# Default Filter in Odoo 8

Tags: xpath, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

Good Day ! Ive Create a Custom Filter and want it to be Default Filter in Attendance but its not working can someone help me with this problem here is my code

```
<record id="view_hr_attendance_main_filter" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Attendances</field>
    <field name="model">hr.attendance.main</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search string="Attendance">
            <filter name="status_payroll" string="Draft" domain="[('attendance_status','=','draft')]" help="Draft Status" select ="1"/>
            <filter name="status_payroll_02" string="Approved" domain="[('attendance_status','=','approved')]" help="Draft Status" select ="1"/>
            <filter name="status_payroll_03" string="Post" domain="[('attendance_status','=','post')]" help="Draft Status" select ="1"/>
            <field name="name"/>
            <field name="assign_projects"/>
            <field name="month_of"/>
            <field name="month_quarter"/>
        </search>
    </field>
</record>

<record id="open_module_hr_attendance_main" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Attendances</field>
    <field name="res_model">hr.attendance.main</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="search_view_id" ref="view_hr_attendance_main_filter"/>
    <field name="context">{"search_default_status_payroll":1}</field>
    <field name="help" type="html">
        <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
            Click to Create an Attendance.
        </p>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: As I understood you expand module hr_attendance?

Comment: No Sir! that is another Model

Comment: I dunno About this but I've Just Set the Value as Boolean (True), Thanks sir for the reply!!

Comment: This is strange because integer values must work the same. [Here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/crm/crm_lead_menu.xml#L16) example from base *crm* module. Maybe problem was in cache or something else.

Answer (score 0):

I've just set the  value as Boolean

```
<field name="context">{"search_default_status_payroll":True}</field>
```

Answer (score 0):

You not need to write above code to apply Default Filter in Attendance.
You need to override the existing action of Attendance. Just write below code in your module and upgrade it, the default filter with status_payroll True is opened.

```
<record id="hr_attendance.open_view_attendance" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="context">{"search_default_status_payroll":1}</field>
</record>
```

Please let me know if you need any other information.